Does Power Apps gateway work with non-Microsoft solutions?
I've been looking around on the Internet for solutions to connect Sharepoint online with a locally running database (Apache-MySQL).
The plan is to allow forms in Sharepoint web parts or applications to save data, which would be sent to Apache and stored on the local database.
Of course, to do so with Sharepoint Online a stable connection needs to be facilitated between Sharepoint and Apache.
I found a few mentions of Power Apps data gateways possibly making this possible. I want to verify this is true.
The Apache webserver, MySQL database is stored on our own intranet. We do not have an on-premises installation of Sharepoint. (Everywhere I looked they used this term "on-premises", but I'm unsure whether this means specifically Sharepoint or any on-premises system)
Examples:
https://simondoy.com/2021/10/10/connecting-sharepoint-online-to-on-premise-databases-with-sharepoint-framework-spfx/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/gateway-reference
Would a Power Apps data gateway allow a connection with non-Microsoft solutions such as Apache?

Why was this question closed? I had adequate information (more than some posts on this forum). Now I edited it to hopefully clarify further. Can I contact whoever closed it, to ask whether they can help?
